# SQL Server combining two table into one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

TBL_PRODUCT_TONNAGE

```
|      Product        |     Jan          | Feb      | Mar    |
+---------------------+------------------+----------+--------+
|     E5000           |       91234      | 110000   | 10001  |
|     E6000           |       81234      | 120000   | 10002  |
|     E7000           |       71234      | 130000   | 10003  |
```

TBL_PRODUCT_CALORIE

```
|      Product        |     Jan          | Feb      | Mar    |
+---------------------+------------------+----------+--------+
|     E5000           |       5010       | 5020     | 5030   |
|     E6000           |       6010       | 6020     | 6030   |
|     E7000           |       7010       | 7020     | 7040   |
```

Is it possible to combine the value into something below 
TBL_PRODUCT_COMBINE

```
|      Product        |     Jan          | Feb      | Mar    |
+---------------------+------------------+----------+--------+
|     E5000           |       91234      | 110000   | 1001   |
|     E5000_cal       |        5010      |   5020   | 5030   |
|     E6000           |       81234      | 120000   | 1002   |
|     E6000_cal       |        6010      |   6020   | 6030   |
|     E7000           |       71234      | 130000   | 1003   |
|     E7000_cal       |        7010      |   7020   | 7030   |
```

please advice

Answer (score 2):

Use `union all`:

```
select    product, jan, feb, mar
from      tbl_product_tonnage

union all
select    product + '_cal', jan, feb, mar
from      tbl_product_calories
```

Are your tables throughput structures for your reporting needs?  Because they aren't normalized, but that's really a different issue than what was asked.

This is to be contrasted with `union`, which does the same thing except that it gets rid of duplicate records.  The results would be the same in your case, but it is more efficient to avoid the de-duplication algorithm if you don't need it.

Comment: I would add some details as to the difference between union and union all

Answer (score 0):

```
select    Product, Jan, Feb, Mar
from      TBL_PRODUCT_TONNAGE
union
select    Product + '_cal', Jan, Feb, Mar
from      TBL_PRODUCT_CALORIE
order by Product
```